# Owner vs. Admin on Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I have already gone through the [official docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Repository+privacy,+permissions,+and+more), but couldn't find the answer.

Are there any actions that the owner of a repository can do, while the admin can't? Specifically I'm interested to know if an Admin can revoke repo access from the owner, effectively kicking out the owner from the list of users?

Comment: I'd imagine that would be the case. Admin would presumably have all access to everything in the ACLs while the owner has similar privileges to admin for his repository only. I'm sure the admin could revoke rights for the owner

Comment: @scrowler: Thanks for the input. My perception is that owner is somehow a higher level authority than an Admin. An Owner can assign "Admin" privileges to a user, but an admin cannot make someone an owner. Also, if what u r seconding is correct, who will have the ownership of the repo once the original owner is kicked out?!